# Doctrine - retrieve collection from a many to many relationship without root entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have 2 entities, say

```
class A
{
...
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="B")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="a_b",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     */
    protected $bs;
...
    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    function getBs()
    {
        return $this->bs;
    }
...
}
```

and

```
class B
{
...
}
```

with a many-to-many relationship defined only on one side (A).

What I'd like to achieve is to fetch a collection of B entities that are related to a single arbitrary A entity using Doctrine's query builder. 
I'm restricted to only do it with the query builder, doing something like `$a->getBs()` is not an option. Same with native sql, defining the relationship on both sides or using repositories, out of the question.

The expected result should look something like

```
[
    B {},
    B {},
]
```

I assumed something like

```
$em = $container->get('doctrine');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('b')
    ->from(A::class, 'a')
    ->join('a.bs', 'b')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('a', ':entity'))
    ->setParameters(['entity' => 1]);

$res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

would work.

Alas, that throws an error `Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`

Tried something like `$qb->select('a.bs')` but that one also throws an error `Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.`

I do have a solution for it (see below), but it's really ugly, so I'm hoping someone has a better one.

```
$qb->select('b')
    ->from(A::class, 'a')
    ->join('a.bs', 'ab')
    ->join(B::class, 'b', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('ab.id', 'b.id'))
```

I'd be grateful if someone could offer some advice.

Answer (score 1):

In this case root entity is A - it must be in select method. 
You can try something like that:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('a, bs')
    ->from(A::class, 'a')
    ->leftJoin('a.bs', 'bs')
    ->where('a.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', 1)
;

$entityA = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
$entityA->getBs(); // Returns all bs from entity A with id 1
```

Comment: Like I wrote earlier, I can't use $entityA->getBs(). The entity is already loaded in the entity manager, so is the collection. I'm actually trying to retrieve the original entities of a collection that was clear()'d.